# Continously deploy from Unity Cloud Build to Google Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, unity3d-cloud-build, unity-cloud-build

Are there any deployment tools that bridges the gap between Unity Cloud Build and the Google Play Store in order to continuously deploy generated APKs to the store?

Comment: i didn't find any direct linking. do share here if you find any. Indirect way is using https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane ( Create a github automation build from Unity Cloud and send it to fastlane )?

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but still very valid. I've been messing with this for a while. Used to have a ridiculously complicated bash script for this, until I realized that fastlane is installed, and you can easily use it in a bash script in the post build event. Now it's literally a 4 line script (minus comments), here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Passed in as environment variables from CI, you must get this from Google and put
# it in the environment variable PLAYSTORE_KEY in the Unity build config.
# $PLAYSTORE_KEY - The JSON file with the credentials for the Google Developer account

# You can also just hardcode your package name, e.g. com.candycrush.game or whatever here...
PACKAGE_NAME=$(cat "$WORKSPACE/build.json" | jq -j '.[].bundleid')

# Unity environment variables replace the "\n" signs from the private key with spaces for some reason,
# so we replaces spaces with "\n" signs again so it works properly.
KEY_WITH_NEWLINES=$(echo $PLAYSTORE_KEY | jq '.private_key |= sub(" (?!PRIVATE|KEY)"; "\n"; "g")' -c -j)

# You could also use shorter argument names here, but DO NOT use -e for --release-status, there's some error there where
# fastlane thinks -e should mean the -env option and fails.
# Also, you could put the "draft" and "internal" into environment variables if you want to never have to modify the script
# again and just control it with environment variables.
fastlane supply --package_name "$PACKAGE_NAME" --aab "$UNITY_PLAYER_PATH"  --json_key_data "$KEY_WITH_NEWLINES" --release-status draft --track internal
```

So just put that in a "upload.sh" file, add it as the post build file in the build config. Get your google key in json format and put it in as the env variable "PLAYSTORE_KEY". No additional fastlane configuration is needed, which was a pleasant surprise, it actually works with just the right parameters passed in.

Comment: could you please elaborate how to get your key in json format?

Comment: You need to create a service account, then you get its credentials as a json file. See https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account

Comment: thanks! I thought I had to do something with Android studio. That makes more sense.

Comment: I had luck following these instructions for the JSON key: http://help.mystudio.io/en/articles/2687493-how-to-create-your-google-json-file-and-share-google-developer-api-access

Comment: Is the fastlane CLI already present on the build agent in UCB? No need to install it?

Comment: Yes, it's already there, no extra installation needed.

Comment: What about the $UNITY_PLAYER_PATH, how can I get that (after a build)?

Comment: @MEMark what do you mean? Get it how? Not just read the environment variable?

Comment: @EinarEgilsson Oh, I didn't know there even was such an env var! (That documentation is quite poor.) Same goes for $PACKAGE_NAME then, it just exists?